# Show $\binom{k+1}{r}+\binom{k+1}{r+1} = \binom{k+2}{k+1} $

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I have been attempting to show $$\binom{k+1}{r}+\binom{k+1}{r+1} = \binom{k+2}{r+1} $$ and my work is

$$\binom{k+1}{r}+\binom{k+1}{r+1} = \frac{(k+1)!}{r!((k+1)-r)!} + \frac{(k+1)!}{(r+1)!((k+1)-(r+1))!}$$

$$=\frac{(k+1)!(r+1)}{(r+1)!((k+1)-r)!} + \frac{(k+1)!
\color{red}{(k-r)}}{(r+1)!((k+1)-(r+1))!\color{red}{(k-r)}}$$

$$=(k+1)!\frac{k+1}{(r+1)!((k+1)-r)!}$$

which [appears correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28+%28%28k%2B1%29%21%28r%2B1%29%29%2F%28%28r%2B1%29r%21%28k%2B1-r%29%21%29+%2B+%28%28k%2B1-r%29%28k%2B1%29%21%29%2F%28%28r%2B1%29%21%28k%2B1-%28r%2B1%29%29%21%28k%2B1-r%29%29++%29+-+binomial%28k%2B2%2Cr%2B1%29). But I am having trouble seeing the final step; where does the $(k+2)$ come from?

Somewhere I've made a mistake but I just don't see it.

Comment: How does an equation "lead to" an expression here? Are you saying you've rewritten the left-hand side of the equation in that form?

Comment: I think there are typos here. You have $\binom{k+1}{r}+\binom{k+1}{r+1}$ is a quantity that depends upon both, $k$ and $r$, but the RHS depends only upon $k$.

Comment: I get $$\binom{k+1}{r}+\binom{k+1}{r+1}=(k+1)!\left[\frac{1}{r!(k+1-r)!}+\frac{1}{(r+1)!(k-r)!}\right]$$ $$=\frac{(k+1)!}{r!(k-r)!}\left[\frac{1}{k+1-r}+\frac{1}{r+1}\right]=\frac{(k+1)!}{r!(k-r)!}\left[\frac{(k+1-r)+(r+1)}{(k+1-r)(r+1)}\right]=\cdots$$ Do your work again. Better yet, show us your work. Notice how the final numerator on the right-hand side of my last expression has two $1$s. Also your W|A link seems to verify that the original equation is true, but I don't understand what you think it says about the expression you were led to.

Comment: Your initial expression is equivalent on the RHS to $k+2$.  Is this what you intended?

Comment: @Trevor You made a mistake adding the fractions. In the left side you should have multiplied by $k+1-r$ instead of $k-r$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\binom{k+1}{r} = \frac{(k+1)!}{(k+1-r)!r!}$ and $\binom{k+1}{r+1} = \frac{(k+1)!}{(k+1-(r+1))!(r+1)!} = \frac{(k+1)!}{(k-r)!(r+1)!}$. Both have a common factor of $\frac{(k+1)!}{(k-r)!r!}$ so let's factor that out to get

$$\binom{k+1}{r}+\binom{k+1}{r+1} = \frac{(k+1)!}{(k-r)!r!}\left(\frac{1}{k+1-r}+\frac{1}{r+1}\right).$$

Making a common denominator, we have

$$\binom{k+1}{r}+\binom{k+1}{r+1} = \frac{(k+1)!}{(k-r)!r!}\cdot\frac{r+1+k+1-r}{(k+1-r)(r+1)}.$$

Notice we can simplify the numerator some to get $k+2$. Rewriting we have

$$\binom{k+1}{r}+\binom{k+1}{r+1} = \frac{(k+1)!}{(k-r)!r!}\cdot\frac{k+2}{((k+1)-r)(r+1)}.$$

Notice that we have $(k-r)!(k+1-r) = (k+1-r)! = ((k+2)-(r+1))!$. So we get

$$\binom{k+1}{r}+\binom{k+1}{r+1} =\frac{(k+2)(k+1)!}{((k+2)-(r+1))!(r+1)r!} = \frac{(k+2)!}{((k+2)-(r+1))!(r+1)!}.$$

Thus,

$$\binom{k+1}{r}+\binom{k+1}{r+1} = \binom{k+2}{r+1}.$$

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want to show $\binom{k+1}{r}+\binom{k+1}{r+1}=\binom{k+2}{r+1}$. It is easier to prove this combinatorically.

Say we have $k+2$ people, and we want to pick a team $r+1$ of them. There are two options, we can either have a particular person call it $x$ in the team, in which there are now $\binom{k+1}{r}$ ways to choose the remaining people, or we cannot have $x$ in the team in which there are now $\binom{k+1}{r+1}$ ways to pick a team (we have $k+1$ to choose from because we are avoiding $x$). Hence, we have our desired identity.

Comment: That makes sense and looks so close to a [combinatorial proof at artofproblemsolving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Combinatorial_identity) which I'll probably ask about next.

Answer (score 0):

Without assuming much, we have (just by definition):

$\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r-1}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)! r!}+\frac{n!}{(n-(r-1))! (r-1)!}$

$\frac{n!}{(n-r)! r!}+\frac{n!}{(n-(r-1))! (r-1)!}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)! r!}+\frac{n!}
{(n-r+1))! (r-1)!}$

$\frac{n!}{(n-r)! r!}+\frac{n!}
{(n-r+1))! (r-1)!}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!(r-1)!}(\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{n-r+1})$

$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!(r-1)!}(\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{n-r+1})=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!(r-1)!}(\frac{n-r+1+r}{r.(n-r+1)})$

$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!(r-1)!}(\frac{n-r+1+r}{r.(n-r+1)})=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!(r-1)!}(\frac{n+1}{r.(n-r+1)})$

$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!(r-1)!}(\frac{n+1}{r.(n-r+1)})=\frac{(n+1)n!}{(n-r+1)(n-r)!.r(r-1)!}$

$\frac{(n+1)n!}{(n-r+1)(n-r)!.r(r-1)!}=\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-r+1)!r!}=\frac{(n+1)!}{((n+1)-r)!.r!}=\binom{n+1}{r}$

Thus, we conclude that $\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r-1}=\binom{n+1}{r}$

replacing $n$ by $n+1$ we get $\binom{n+1}{r}+\binom{n+1}{r-1}=\binom{n+2}{r}$

replacing $r$ by $r+1$ we get  $\binom{n+1}{r+1}+\binom{n+1}{r}=\binom{n+2}{r+1}$

The reason i have proved for $n$ is just my comfort and nothing much :P